# Can we able to access local Whatsapp messages from my app in react native?

Tags: react-native, whatsapp

Can we able to get the Whatsapp messages when someone sends a message to my app?

Comment: Do you have an API?

Comment: Nope
I would like to get my local WhatsApp content.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is “NOT POSSIBLE”

Whatsapp uses end to end encrypted msgs and even you have no api to access whatsapp data.

Comment: I just want to know my local WhatsApp content buddy

Comment: Sorry you cannot access.

Comment: end-to-end encryption doesn't really matter here. The real issue is that WhatsApp doesn't have an API

Comment: In any case, can we able to capture the data from the notifications of other apps in react native?